# Valuables in Accountant's trailer drawer

Tags: the-accountant

In [The Accountant](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2140479/) Christian Wolff stores valuable items, cash, weapons, identities and everything that holds value to him in his "storage on wheel" trailer. For example he has valuable paintings, that he has taken as a form of payment. I assume the comics and baseball cards in the image below are of similar category - having value in money among collectors. **My question is, what are those cards under the comics in the picture below next to baseball cards?** This is the best frame I found of it and can't tell what they are.

[image: Stuff]

Are those also Baseball cards? If yes, then what era are they from?

Comment: I don't see anything other than baseball cards...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are all real baseball cards.

The one on the left displays Horus Wagner. The T206 Wagner is the most valuable baseball card in existence, and even damaged examples are valued at $100'000 or more.

He played in the Major League from July 19, 1897, for the Louisville Colonels to his last MLB appearance in September 17, 1917, for the Pittsburgh Pirates.
Mid 2007, one of these cards was sold for 2.8 million Dollars.
It was part of the tobacco card set, known as T206. It was issued from 1909 to 1911.

the player: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honus_Wagner

the card: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T206_Honus_Wagner

the deck: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T206

The yellow one is "T 205 Hoblitzell". I believe the value to be around $100 (don't get me on this).

And the last one is a "1915 Cracker Jack Mathewson". (PSA Mint 9 Mathewson#88) sold for $41'125 in 2009.

By the way, the right comic is "Action Comics #1" (June 1938): It’s the first appearance of Superman and Lois Lane, and the most valuable comic of all time. Record sale price: $3.2 million

The one on the left is "All-American Comics #16" (July 1940): It’s the first appearance and the origin story of the Green Lantern. Record sale price: $203,000